# Selecting a random column from a group of columns of interest

Tags: sas

I am trying to come up with code that will select a random column from a group of columns on interest. The group of columns will change depending on the values in the columns for each observation. Each observation is a subject.

Let me explain to be more clear:

I have 8 columns, names V1-V8. Each column has 3 potential responses ('Small','Medium','High'). Due to certain circumstances in our project, I need to "combine" all this information into 1 column.

Key factor 1: We only want the columns per subject where he/she selected 'High' (lots of combinations here). This is what I refer to when I say the columns of interest changes per subject.

Key factor 2: Once I have identified the columns where 'High' was selected for the subject, select one of the columns at random.

At the end, I need a new variable (New_V) with values V1-V8 (NOT 'Small','Medium','High') indicating which column was selected for each subject.

Any advice would be great. I have tried ARRAYs and Macro variables but I can seem to tackle this the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method uses macro variables and a loop. There are three main steps: First, find all variables that are "high." Second, select a random value from 1 to the number of variables that are "high." Third, pick that variable and call it selected_var.

```
data temp;
   input subject $ v1 $ v2 $ v3 $ v4 $ v5 $ v6 $ v7 $ v8 $;
   datalines;
    1 high medium small high medium small high medium
    2 medium small high medium small high medium high
    3 small high high medium small high medium high
    4 medium medium high medium small small medium medium
    5 medium medium high small small high medium small
    6 small small high medium small high high high
    7 small small small small small small small small
    8 high high high high high high high high
    ;
run;

%let vars = v1 v2 v3 v4 v5 v6 v7 v8;

%macro find_vars;

    data temp2;
        set temp;

            /*find possible variables*/
            format possible_vars $20.;
            %do i = 1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&vars.));
            %let this_var = %scan(&vars., &i.);
                if &this_var. = "high" then possible_vars = cats(possible_vars, "&this_var.");
            %end;

            /*create a random integer between 1 and number of variables to select from*/
            rand = 1 + floor((length(possible_vars) / 2) * rand("Uniform"));

            /*pick that one!*/
            selected_var = substr(possible_vars, (rand * 2 - 1), 2);
    run;

%mend find_vars;

%find_vars;
```

[image]

Comment: I would use `catx` with a delimiter and `scan` - feels safer if nothing else and less multiplying required.  Ultimately not sure I see what value is added by the macro over using array processing, but it is interesting to see the alternate solution for sure.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help! I was on the right track but I didn't how to concatenate the potential variables into one string. This worked perfectly.

Comment: Glad to hear it. You should take Joe's advice on the concatenation with a delimiter though; that's a cleaner way of going about this.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track with arrays.  The `vname` function will be helpful here. The `want` datastep shows how to do this (the rest just sets up example data):

```
proc format;
  value smh
    1='Small'
    2='Medium'
    3='High'
    other=' '
  ;
quit;
data have;
  call streaminit(5);
  array v[8] $;
  do _i = 1 to 1000;
    do _j = 1 to 8;
      __rand = ceil(1+rand('Binomial',.7,2));
      v[_j] = put(__rand,smh6.);
    end;
    if whichc('High',of v[*]) = 0 then v8 = 'High';  *guarantee have one high;
    output;
  end;
  drop _:;
run;

data want;
  call streaminit(7);  *arbitrary seed here, pick any positive number;
  set have;
  array v[8] ;
  do until (v[_rand] = 'High');  *repeat this loop until one is picked that is High;
    _rand = ceil(8*rand('Uniform'));  
  end;
  chosen_v = vname(v[_rand]);  *assign the chosen name to chosen_v variable;
  drop _:; 
run;

proc freq data=want;
  tables chosen_v;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I am personally a bit more familiar with macro functions than arrays so I will implement the macro solution, but yours definitely improved my knowledge of arrays.

Comment: @bvm182 I would strongly suggest learning arrays, and eventually using this method. The macro method really adds nothing other than complexity - arrays are the way to go for this particular problem, it's why they exist.